# AngularJS: $rootScope.$on not receiving msg sent via $rootScope.$broadcast on v1.2 of angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

has something changed between angular 1.2 rc2 and angular 1.2 with regards to broadcast and receiving the broadcast ?

I have what I think is a standard broadcast in a controller in a $watch i.e.

```
    $scope.$watch('changedRequest', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('onTestingMe')
    });
```

and I try to receive it in another controller like so

```
    $rootScope.$on("onTestingMe", function () {
        alert('I am received');
    });
```

The broadcast seems to work but I never get anything arriving in $on.

I have set the $on and $broadcast on the $rootScope. My watch is on a $scope but this shouldn't be an issue.

I am injecting $rootScope in both controllers.

There are no errors being received in the chrome console.

I am lost, any ideas ?

I did notice the same happening on RC3 but I just put this down to an RC, so I went back to RC2 and thought I would wait for 1.2 Release.... but the same is happening..

**EDIT**

The only thing I can see that is different is that I am using a  ng-include

```
        <div ng-include="template.url" ng-controller="ItemBarCtrl"></div>
```

Maybe its not rendering quick enough ? As the msg is sent when document is loaded and the controller ItemBarCtrl has the $on ....

I will try and do some testing...  Strange issue!

Comment: I have also tried changing the $rootScope.$on to $scope.$on but still no luck.

Comment: to push up from scope use `$emit`....`$broadcast` pushes down through nested scopes from where it starts, `$emit` goes up through parent scopes  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: @charlietfl, the docs state that: `The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified.` it shouldn't be the problem :P

Comment: That code should work, could you write a plunker that reproduces the error?

Comment: @rvignacio right above that they also state `Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered `....note keyword `child`...But OP says is trying to broadcast from scope

Comment: @charlietfl, [here's $broadcast's function code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0/src/ng/rootScope.js#L963-L997). It first sets `target`, `current` and `next` as `this`, then it calls all of `current` listeners. So, it is really starting at the scope on which $broadcast was called.

Comment: Thanks for everyones comments, I have updated my question. I am going to do some further testing but the only thing that is strange is I am doing a ng-include but I was doing the same before the update.

Comment: Ok putting the contrioller above on a Div seemed to sort it out, it seems that the item is not being rendered quick enough using ng-include. Anyone know if this is the correct solution, it certainly works.

Comment: @Martin I am experiencing the exact same thing. I am also using include. Did you get anywhere with this issue?

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but I came across it searching for a similar problem. Try wrapping your `$broadcast` in a `$timeout` function with a delay of 100 or so. If the `$on` fires, then it's likely the same problem I'm running in to where the `$broadcast` fires before the `$on` is ready. I'm still investigating the issue for a fix.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me as well. In my case I was responding to a $location change on back arrow and calling a method that re-displays the original content.

Comment: I had the same problem with a `broadcast` between a `service` and a `directive` and this solution worked for me.